# Is there a difference between using a DynamicHyperLink or a LinkButton in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Basically, is there any performance or rendering advantage to using one over the other?

**Edit** for clarification:
Both can be assigned a `CommandName` and `ComandArgument`, but is there a difference in postback types?

Comment: What is a `dynamichyperlink`? What are you comparing? In general, use the appropriate control for your requirement, not what might render a millisecond faster.

Comment: DynamicHyperlink > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.dynamichyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know this control. I thought that it was just a typo.

Comment: I didn't either, just decided to look it up and didn't find much info on it. Figured I would ask.

Comment: I think he/she ask a good question, any reason for downvote ?!

Comment: This looks like a control explicitly created to be used with Dynamic Data. I'm certainly not an expert though. Here's an article I found that references it: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/10/what-are-differences-between-aspnet-35.html

Comment: The best information that I've been able to find is that when using the DynamicHyperlink, you can target a table in a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. DynamicHyperLink is not meant for regular GridView use. It's for the ASP.NET Dynamic Data framework. It has extra functionality that is not needed for non Dynamic Data situations. You shouldn't use it unless you're doing Dynamic Data because you don't need that overhead.

You can think of a LinkButton as merely a Button that renders as an `<a>` tag instead of `<input type="button">`. Clicking it posts back to the server and calls the `OnClick` handler in the same way, and you can have client side code execute before with `OnClientClick`.

It's really apples and oranges.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the postback for dynamic hyperlinks in a javascript like as below,

hrefLetter.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "letterHrefClick('" + items.letterName + wordDocExtension + "')");

_doPostBack("hdnLetterClick", "somevalue");

But in case of linkbuttons there is some problems of postback not firing...
The general reason for the problem would be when they are not the childs of the webpage.
Though you can clear the problem by creating a list of link controls instead of dynamically creating, it may trouble you...

Answer (score -1):

The HyperLink control:
navigates to the target URL Immediately when user clicks on it. 
The form is not posted to the server.

The LinkButton control:
it will first posts the form to the server, then navigates to the URL.

If you need to do any server-side processing before going to the target URL, use a LinkButton. 
On the other hand, if there is no server-side processing necessary, don't waste a round trip and use the HyperLink control.

references:
LinkButton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cd4z1zs(v=vs.71).aspx

Hyperlink: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0b15efk(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: -1 LinkButton doesn't take a navigation URL, as shown in the documentation you linked to. It's merely an `asp:Button` that renders as a hyperlink. And this question isn't about the `asp:HyperLink` control, it's about `asp:DynamicHyperLink`.